# mod_rewrite vs mod_substitute | How can i differentiate them?

Tags: apache, url, aem, dispatcher

I am new in dispatcher in AEM. I am not able to understand the mod_rewite and mod_substitute in the dispatcher rewrite rule.
When does mod_rewite comes into the picture and when mod_substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both modules are used for different purposes. The documentation states:

**mod_substitute**

> Perform search and replace operations on response bodies

That means:

1. Works with the outgoing *response*
2. With mod_substitute you can change *what* is send back to the browser. You can for example change the HTML (to a certain degree).

**mod_rewrite**

> Provides a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite requested URLs on the fly

That means:

1. Works with the incoming *request*
2. Allows you to change *where* an incoming request is send to.

From personal experience I would say that 99,9% you are going to work with `mod_rewrite` in AEM projects.

**Links**

1. [Documentation mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html)
2. [Documentation mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)